# I want to change the color of the first Button, when I clicked on the second

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to coding. I found a inspiration and started making my website. I made a logo and 2 buttons, Shots and Designers. When I click on the first and the second button, they both change their color to white, but thats not what I want. I want that when I click on the second button, the first button change this color to start color (grey).I mean if button 2 clicked, change button 1 color to grey.
Here is my code:

````
 <head>
 <title>Richis corner</title>
 </head>
 <head>
 <style>
 .rectangle {
   height: 85px;
   width: 4500px;
   background-color: #242526;
   margin-top: -43px;
   margin-left: -8px;
}
.image {
  margin-top: -147px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.button1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background: none;
  color: grey;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="rectangle"></div>
<img src=https://i.yapx.ru/Koe4kb.png" class="image">
<button style="margin:-37px -25px;position: absolute;" class="button1" id="demo" onclick="myButton()"> 
Shots</button>
<button style="margin:-37px 50px;position: absolute;" class="button1" id="demo2" 
onclick="mysecondButton()"> Designers</button>
<script>
function myButton() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "white";
  }
function mysecondButton() {
  document.getElementById("demo2").style.color = "white";
  }
</script>
</body>```
````

Comment: You can change it back to default (or rather, whatever the CSS defines) with `.style.color = "";`. You should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: I want that to be like: if button 2 clicked, change button 1 color to grey, but how do I write it as code?

Comment: The exact same way you have button 2 being made white, but with button 1 and grey.

Comment: So you know how to make a button color white, but don't know how to make it grey ? What is going on !

Comment: No. I cant explain it right. if button 2 clicked, change button 1 color to grey.

Comment: Dear user. You have a function that gets triggered when you click button2 named `mysecondButton()` . In that function you change the color of button2 ( the clicked one ) into `white` with `document.getElementById("demo2").style.color = "white" ` . Just instead of this line, get the demo ( button1 ) element and change the color into gray or default.

Comment: Any answer to your problem probably works. Just try them out and tell them what's wrong with them.

Comment: Thank you, You saved me! I just didnt understand what you mean at first.

Comment: Yes I tried out thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myButton() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "white";
}
function mysecondButton() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "grey";
}
```

Comment: No, not like that, I mean if button 2 clicked, change button 1 color to grey

Comment: Yes, I changed it. Please try my code now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your change

```js
<script>
    function myButton() {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "white";
    }
    function mysecondButton() {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "grey";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How do I write it as "if button 2 clicked, change button 1 color to grey"?